# AWS Connection refused from public ip when using https

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, flask, amazon-ec2

I have a python-flask web app running in a docker on an AWS EC2 instance. I am using python-sslify to force https, but I am getting a 'Connection refused.' I made sure port 80 was open in the security group's inbound rules, and opened port 443. If I turn off sslify, everything runs fine, just not secured. With sslify on I get the following:

```
$ curl https://localhost
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
$ curl https://ec2-**-**-***-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com/login
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ec2-**-**-***-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 443: Connection refused
```

As far as I can tell the gnutls_handshake error is an issue with an old version of curl, so I've concluded that it's working correctly, just not open to the internet. Viewing the server's debug output I can see that a connection comes in, receives the 302 redirect to https, but that's. Port 80 is definitely open and working fine, port 443 is not and I'm not sure why. Is there somewhere else I need to open port 443 other than the security group's inbound rules?

Here are the inbound rules, btw. Also, the server is running on 0.0.0.0:8000 in the docker with ports 80, 443, and 8000 exposed.
[image: Inbound Rules]

EDIT:
Request to telnet 443:

```
$ telnet localhost 443
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
$ telnet ec2-**-**-***-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com 443
Trying **-**-***-***...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

EDIT 2:
Netstat test:

```
$ netstat -a -n -t | grep ':443.*LISTEN'
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: You may need [`ProxyFix`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.14.x/contrib/fixers/#werkzeug.contrib.fixers.ProxyFix). See usage [here](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/v0.13.0/proxies.html) (ignore the fact that it's a specific library). Oddly, I was fighting with redirects going from https to http just today but with NginX

Comment: No luck... Cool library, though.

Comment: did you try telnet port 443 . If not, please try and post your result

Comment: "telnet: could not resolve port/443: Name or service not known." Is that useful?

Comment: can you post the telnet command you entered as it is

Comment: Added it to the original question.

Comment: Ok can you run telnet from your computer `telnet ec2-**-**-***-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com 443`.  also can you run the telnet command from inside the instance `telnet localhost 443`

Comment: Tried both of those and put them in the original question.

Comment: Are you certain that your SSL setup is correct?

Comment: Connection refused from outside would not be caused by security groups but rather by there being no listening socket bound to the outside-facing interface. What does `netstat -a -n -t | grep ':443.*LISTEN'` show?

Comment: Added the netstat output to the original question. Looks like something is listening on 443... Its identical to the output running the command on port 80, and that's certainly the web app because nothing is listening on those ports when it isn't running.